# Illustrator CS4: Default opacity of new objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, illustration, cs4

I'm working on a document in which I need each new object to be the same opacity as the last created. It seems that the only thing that carries over to the next new object is the stroke and fill of the last. Thus, each time I start drawing a new object, I have to reset the opacity...

Yes, I could just select all necessary objects and set their opacity at once, **but** it's important that I see what's going on in below layers while each new path is being drawn, so having a default opacity for new objects would be extremely helpful in this scenario.

Is there any such thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply ensure the New Art Has Basic Appearance is **not** selected in the Appearance Panel menu.

[image: appearance panel CS4]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Now I can seamlessly draw with opacity on!